# Pass statically declared __constant__ variable as kernel parameter (CUDA)

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to pass statically allocated __constant__ variables as kernel parameters, but something seems to be wrong. Kernel behaves as variables are not initialized. But still, I can access variables as global variables (from the same kernel). Modifying variables values from the host works, but again, only if I access variables from the global scope. Here is an example:

```
#include<cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<stdio.h>

__constant__ float constant_a=1.12345;
__constant__ float constant_b;

__global__ void test_values(float a, float b) {
    printf("Device code: constant_a = %f, constant_b = %f\n", a, b);
    printf("Device code: constant_a = %f, constant_b = %f\n\n", constant_a, constant_b);
}

int main() {
    test_values<<<1, 1>>>(constant_a, constant_b);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    const float h_const_a = 1;
    const float h_const_b = 2;

    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constant_a, &h_const_a, sizeof(float));
    test_values<<<1, 1>>>(constant_a, constant_b);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constant_b, &h_const_b, sizeof(float));
    test_values<<<1, 1>>>(constant_b, constant_b);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

The kernel prints out this:

```
Device code: constant_a = 0.000000, constant_b = 0.000000
Device code: constant_a = 1.123450, constant_b = 0.000000

Device code: constant_a = 0.000000, constant_b = 0.000000
Device code: constant_a = 1.000000, constant_b = 0.000000

Device code: constant_a = 0.000000, constant_b = 0.000000
Device code: constant_a = 1.000000, constant_b = 2.000000
```

If anyone can explain this, I would also very much appreciate if you can provide me with the source of information. Since I didn't found this information in Nvidia Guide or few other books.

Comment: `__constant__` and `__device__` variables exist at global scope.  There is no need to pass them as parameters, and indeed you should not use them that way.  Just use them in your code, as if they were available globally within the module.  Because they are.  One of the places this is documented is [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#constant) "Is accessible from all the threads within the grid" means that it is accessible without requiring you to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: All kernel parameters are accessible to all threads in the grid, so there would be no need to point this out with that wording, if the intention was that you still have to pass these variables as parameters.  That is not the intention.  The intention is that they are *automatically* accessible to all threads in a grid, when you decorate with `__constant__`.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you very much for you response! I read documentation, but I didn't found that passing them as parameters is wrong, so I thought maybe I can use both approaches - to pass  __constant__ variable the same way as passing dynamically allocated device arrays. Anyway, I was wrong, but I still think Nvidia should put that info somewhere more explicitly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to pass statically allocated `__constant__` variables as
>   kernel parameters, but something seems to be wrong

What is wrong is that you can't do that. It isn't supported.

> Kernel behaves as variables are not initialized

Because they are not initialized. `__constant__` variables cannot be accessed in host code, except by the symbol manipulation APIs. And when you use those APIs, you are only modifying values in device memory. Nothing else. The host side variables associated with statically declared device symbols exist only as tags for binding the API calls to. Changes in device memory are not reflected in the host memory. The only exception to this is `__managed__` symbols (on platforms where that is supported).

> Modifying variables values from the host works, but again, only if I
>   access variables from the global scope

That is the only valid and supported use case for `__constant__` variables in host code.

> Since I didn't found this information in Nvidia Guide or few other books.

You didn't find the information about how to do this because it doesn't exist, and that is because it isn't supported. You can find a concise description of what is supported [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#constant).